# How append to already appended div?

Tags: jquery

I need to append html content to an already appented div.

```
$("#add").click(function(e){ 
   $('.wrapper').append('<div class="input_fields_wrap"></div>');
});
```

Now I need to append to "div.input_fields_wrap". But the below code do not work.

```
$("#add2").click(function(e){
    $('.input_fields_wrap').append('...'); 
});
```

Comment: Can you add more details.. Its confusing..

Comment: *"But the below code do not work."* It should do, provided the `#add2` element exists as of when the `$(#add2).click(...)` runs. Can you create an [MCVE](/help/mcve)?

Comment: I think because you are adding the element dynamically after page load you will need to look into event delegation http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/

Comment: that is because jquery cache your dom. $() selector search within cached dom. if you use the .find method you will be able to find it. Eg.   $('#container_whatever_your_field_Container_is').find('.input_fields_wrap').append(...);

Comment: This seems to work [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/n7n8huqq/)

Comment: @Ji_in_coding: jQuery does not cache the DOM.

Comment: @RobSchmuecker What's the need of event delegation here?? Is op binding any events to the newly appended element?

Comment: This mentioned code should work perfectly well - proof here -> http://jsfiddle.net/pdn9Lfma/ you must have some othes issues that are breaking the code, perhaps misspelled id's, incorrect class names or similar.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder oh, thanks for pointing that out. I was always under the wrong impression it does. I'll read up a bit

Comment: @Ji_in_coding: When you use jQuery, **you** might cache elements (not the DOM as a whole), but jQuery doesn't. `var x = $("selector")` creates a jQuery object that has references to the elements matching the selector. If you remove those elements from the DOM, but keep that object, you'll be (in effect) caching those elements. But jQuery doesn't.

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy as I said ... I *think* this is what's going on.  The question isn't particularly clear but he may well be adding `#add2` in the first `#add` listener.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
$("#add2").click(function(e){
    $('body').find('.input_fields_wrap').append('...'); 
});
```